# When to access subview properties in UIViewController Lifecycle?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift, lifecycle

Context of Problem:

I am trying to learn how to use the storyboard in Xcode 6 by placing three UIViews in the storyboard's topmost viewcontroller. One of the UIView's is blue, one is red, and one is yellow. I am trying to see if I can alter the UIView's programmatically by changing the background color of one of the UIViews. By Command + clicking the UIViewController class and looking at the appropriate functions to override, I've determined "viewDidAppear" is the final function to be called by the UIViewController in its setup code.

Problem:

Here is my override of the function:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.bottomView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}
```

However, when I run this code the the screen with the three UIViews appears for a split second, with NO black-colored UIView, and then proceeds to crash with a

```
"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
```

Question:

What function do I have to override in order to be able to programmatically change the properties of the UIView? What is the best-practices method of doing so?

EDIT:

I am using Storyboard so my three UIView's are declared in the beginning of my UIViewController class as such:

```
@IBOutlet var topLeftView: UIView?
@IBOutlet var topRightView: UIView?
@IBOutlet var bottomView: UIView?
```

It seems that none of the views are actually initialized when viewDidLoad gets called, because the result of the following line of code

```
println("\(bottomView?)")
```

is "nil". How come this isn't getting initialized?

Answer (score 0):

This is best done in `viewDidLoad`. `viewDidAppear` is called when the view is added into the view hierarchy, but it was not yet initiated. `viewDidLoad` is called when the view is allocated into memory. According to the docs for `viewDidLoad`:

`You usually override this method to perform additional initialization on views that were loaded from nib files`

You should override `viewDidLoad` and modify your `UIView`'s in there.

Comment: I edited my initial post in response to your suggestion.